# 'pub get' gives an error for Angular2 package

Tags: dart, angular

I have a 'pubspec.yaml' with below content:

```
# #docregion
name: angular2_tour_of_heroes
version: 0.0.1
environment:
  sdk: '>=1.13.0 <2.0.0'
dependencies:
  angular2: 2.0.0-beta.15
  browser: ^0.10.0
  dart_to_js_script_rewriter: ^1.0.1
transformers:
- angular2:
    platform_directives:
    - package:angular2/common.dart#COMMON_DIRECTIVES
    platform_pipes:
     - package:angular2/common.dart#COMMON_PIPES
    entry_points: web/main.dart
```

When I run 'pub get' in command line, get below error:

```
Resolving dependencies... 
Got dependencies!
Precompiling dependencies... 
Loading source assets... 
Loading angular2/transform/codegen, dart_to_js_script_rewriter, observe and smokLoading angular2/transform/codegen, dart_to_js_script_rewriter, observe and smokLoading angular2/transform/codegen, dart_to_js_script_rewriter, observe and smoke/src/default_transformer transformers... 
Transformer library "package:angular2/transform/codegen.dart" not found.
```

How do I fix it?

Create bug report: https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues/1406

Comment: I tried your `pubspec.yaml` locally and it resolved fine. You could try `pub cache repair` on the command line and then try again. If your project directory contains a `.pub` directory, you can try deleting it as well (maybe even before you try `pub cache repair`)

Comment: i did it. does not work. i get same error yet

Comment: Weird. What Dart version? What OS?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer  Dart VM version: 1.15.0 on "linux_x64" (i have manjaro)

Comment: Are you working on a network drive?

Comment: no. i use proxy to access to `pub.dartlang.org`

Comment: Ok, pretty sure it is related to the proxy. I don't have experience with using proxy myself. It's a bit weird because when transformers are run, the packages are already downloaded to the local disk and no network access should be necessary anymore.

Comment: Looks like https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues/1227

Comment: oic. i am in iran , and i could not access to dartlang. google has blocked us. i have to use proxy, thank you buddy @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: I think it's a bug if using a proxy causes this issue. Can you please check if the file actually exists on your disk?

Comment: yeah, there is a `codegen.dart`  file in the path: `package:angular2/transform/codegen.dart`

Comment: I suggest creating a bug report in https://github.com/dart-lang/pub

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and spent a ton of time trying to fix it. My root cause was after I migrated to a new computer. My hosts file did not migrate. Once I added `127.0.0.1 localhost` to my hosts file it started working.