# Dart number_format.dart suddenly won't compile

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I made a small change in my server code not related to formatting numbers and now the dart library **number_format.dart** won't compile giving me 12 errors and two warnings.  **number_format** is in **intl** as noted in the comments and the first error is at line 106. Some or most of the other errors appear to cascade from a first error.

Does anyone know how I may resolve this?  I presume I need to edit something in my yaml file.

EDIT

If I choose Tools-> Pub Upgrade then I get the pre-build Problems below This weekend I could choose Tools->Pub Build - Debug but at the moment this does not work.  Deleting .pub and following Günter Zöchbauer's suggestion allowed me to do a build Sunday - I hope is still does.

Pre-build Problems output:

```
Errors:
Line 106: Expected an identifier
Line 106: Expected to find ':'
Line 106: Unexpected token '?'
Line 131: Unexpected token '?'
Line 132: Expected an identifier
Line 132: Expected to find ':'
Line 233: Expected an identifier
Line 233: Expected to find ':'
Line 233: Unexpected token '?'
Line 545: Expected an identifier
Line 545: Expected to find ':'
Line 545: Unexpected token '?'
Warnings:
Line 106: Conditions must have a static type of 'bool'
Line 545: Conditions must have a static type of 'bool' 
Hint:
Line 425: When compiled to JS, this test might return true when the left hand side is an int
```

Thanks

Comment: What errors are you getting? Kinda hard to diagnose with only the file name and the number of errors!

Comment: number_format.dart is a dart library, it's not my code.  I edited my post to make that clear.

Comment: With "compile" you mean `pub build"?

Comment: I'm guessing the file is https://github.com/dart-lang/intl/blob/master/lib/src/intl/number_format.dart - if so, you could file an issue on the github tracker for that project.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yes, 'pub build', that's what I meant.

Comment: You could try deleting the `.pub` directory and then `pub cache repair` if this also doesn't help please create a bug report in https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer It worked.  Thanks for your continuing good advice.  If you post your suggestion for an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Whoops not quite right.  All is well until I do pub upgrade, then I get all the prebuild errors and need to delete .pub etc.

Comment: Looks like a pub issue. Probably related to another bug rported recently.

Comment: Can you please add the concrete error message you get to your question?

Comment: Is it similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36643048/pub-get-gives-an-error-for-angular2-package or https://github.com/dart-lang/test/issues/424?

Comment: I just run into https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues/1407 which also might be similar.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I added the pre-build errors etc. as an edit to the original post.

Comment: Does this mean deleting `.pub` made it work again?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yes, deleting `.pub` followed by `pub cache repair` makes it work again.

Comment: Ok, then it doesn't seem to be a serious issue. Thanks for the feedback.